# Find the basis for $\text{Im} \, ψ$ of a matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\psi\colon\mathrm{Mat}_{ 2\times 2 }(\mathbb R) \to \mathrm{Mat}_{ 2\times 2 }(\mathbb R)$ be defined by

$$\psi\colon \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\to\pmatrix{a+b&a-c\\a+c&b-c}.$$

Find basis for $\operatorname{Im}\psi$ (image of $\psi$) .

Now I have got that the $\operatorname{Im}\psi$ is $\operatorname{span}\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
,\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\
%
,\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 
\end{array} \right)\right\}$.

And that the basis is the set of these matrices: $\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
,\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\
%
,\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 
\end{array} \right)\right\}$ since they are linearly independent.

Am I right about the $\operatorname{Im}\psi$ and it's basis?

Comment: I changed $2x2$ to $2\times 2$, and {$\begin{bmatrix} \bullet \\  \bullet\end{bmatrix}$} (with curly braces outside the math environment) to $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} \bullet \\  \bullet\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ (with the braces inside the math environment), and did some other $\TeX$ improvements.  Putting actual text inside the math environment without using \text{} is not considered correct, and in this case it's better just to put it outside the math environment.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm not too good at the TeX commands.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answers are correct.

Comment: Thank you, when I say "they are linearly independent" about the set of matrices, do I need to add "and also spanning" or not?

Comment: That needs to be true for them to be a basis, but the way you've phrased that sentence it's clear that you are using that they span.